# Visual Studio Code (Server) self update is stuck

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I recently got stuck starting vscode on ubuntu 20.04 (on a WSL)

```
$ code
Updating VS Code Server to version b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a)
Downloading:
```

And then nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the proxy. And the missing link, that VS Code Server uses wget.

Solution was to configure a proxy in `/etc/wgetrc`:

```
use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=12.34.56.78:1234
https_proxy=12.34.56.78:1234
```

BTW: just editing `~/.wgetrc` was not enough.

Comment: "~/.wgetrc was not enough" you said  :-( . What can be suggested if one don't get the root permissions ?

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked to remove "update.code.visualstudio.com" line from ~/.wget-hsts.

Comment: I tried this first and it did not work.  Although ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/jayrae/.vscode-server/bin/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681-1706298021.tar.gz I have a 0 byte file.